# Unit of measurements of energy of particles

Tags: energy, particle-physics

I have come across this unit of measurement eV/q (or eV/e) where q in my understanding is the electron charge. Could anyone clarify how to interpret this unit (electrons and ions energy)?

Comment: Can you see how it is an effective distance, by definition?

Answer (score 0):

The unit of measurement for the energy is $eV$ (electron-volts). Its interpretation is simple: it's the total amount of energy that a particle of charge equal to the measure of the electron charge acquires when it is placed in an electric potential of  $1\, V$. That is of course a very small number, but it is more convenient for any form of fundamental physics, since the various encountered energies are of that order or several orders of magnitude larger. The usual units of measurement such as the Joule are far too large to be of any convenience, just like the Tesla units for magnetic fields (the Gauss units are preferred for most practical calculations).

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, but the unit in this case is indeed eV/q, see https://books.google.nl/books?id=3pBNNEykLIIC&pg=PA159&dq=ion+%22energy+per+charge%22+++definition++-car&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjY3fDaubT4AhVOsKQKHRLYAMAQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=ion%20%22energy%20per%20charge%22%20%20%20definition%20%20-car&f=false

Comment: Then it would imply the energy per unit of charge, modulo the charge of the particle species at hand. The ratio $eV/q$ would give you the value of the potential in volts for which your particle of charge $q$ has the same amount of energy an electron acquires in a potential of  $1 \, V$. I'm no experimental physicist, but I would imagine this could be useful for an apparatus where you can measure the total amount of energy over a pool of the same charged particles and you want to find the measure of the electric potential in which they would need to be to attain the same amount of energy.